# AttributeError: module 'xml.etree.ElementTree' has no attribute 'parse'

Tags: python

Whenever I downloaded the pytmx package I got this AttributeError: module 'xml.etree.ElementTree' has no attribute 'parse'

This is the full error in the pytmx.py file:

```
    if filename:
        self.parse_xml(ElementTree.parse(self.filename).getroot())
```

AttributeError: module 'xml.etree.ElementTree' has no attribute 'parse'

Comment: if your file name `pytmx`? Please avoid using package names as file names.

Comment: Thats how it came when I downloaded it btw I am using pycharm